# HDR bloom techniques using post processing in Unity3D

Tags: unity, post-processing, hdr, bloom

I've seen many posts on how to accomplish HDR bloom effects in Unity3D using its (now legacy) Bloom component as part of the standard assets package.

I'm trying to replicate it using the new post processing package, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have an an emissive material that's emitting at a value far >1 sitting at 10:
[image: material settings]

Bloom is set in a Post Processing Profile, and the threshold is >1:
[image: bloom settings]

Finally, HDR is enabled on my camera, along with a deferred rendering path.
[image: camera settings]

Yet this doesn't work. I only see the bloom effect if I set my bloom threshold <1, after which all my materials bloom. It's as if HDR is not actually enabled. Anyone know why?

Comment: From what I can tell you're using the Post Processing Stack incorrectly. Try the quick start guide here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/PostProcessing/wiki/%28v2%29-Quickstart

Comment: hmm interesting, I downloaded post processing from the asset store and set it up according to this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0OQvWAPeuo) and it does not include some of the scripts outlined in that guide, such as `PostProcessLayer.cs`, *or* `PostProcessVolume.cs`. I'll clone the repo and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The `v2` post processing branch throws infinite null argument errors in the editor from `Dithering.cs`, (but it still runs). I set everything up according to the guide and it is not running, even chromatic aberration, or bloom with a threshold < 1. In my earlier setup, I saw the bloom effect when the threshold was < 1

Comment: Are you on Unity 2017.x?

Comment: Nope, 2016, version 5.6.x I started developing my game in that build and don't want to upgrade in the middle of development. I guess that may be the issue?

Comment: It may well be, but I cannot ensure that. The unity mentions that it's a 5.6 feature (unsure if v1 or v2). So it should probably work anyway. Try a minimal setup with a new project